# ¿Como unir dos listas de modelo persona y cliente asp.net mvc 5 entityframework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

tengo un proyecto en el cual manejo BD con sqlserver, lo que quiero es que al crear en el controlador un metodo con su vista que me retorne una lista con el modelo de persona y cliente en una sola lista para asi mostrarlos en  una tabla

```
private PruebaContext cc = new chalupaContext();
    // GET: cliente
    public ActionResult Clientes()
    {
        List<persona> persona = cc.personas.ToList();
        List<cliente> cliente = cc.clientes.ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

enotnces lo que quiero es ver como puedo unir estas dos en una sola y mandarlas en el return view(listacliente);
ya que manejo el MVC

Comment: Hola. Las clases `persona` y `cliente` son distintas, no? No creo que puede unir dos clases diferentes en una misma `List<>`. Pero si tiene dos listas de mismo tipo (mismo clase), puede usar el metodo [AddRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacer esto; Puedes crear un objecto que contenga las dos listas adentro, pasarle este nuevo objeto a la vista y en la vista iterar ambos objetos  y hacer lo que quieras en el grid... otra forma es crear una clase abstracta y tomar los datos utilizando esta clase abstracta... otra forma es usar automapper y crear un nuevo objeto que tenga los datos que necesitas para el resultado final, con automapper pasar estos datos a la nueva clase y mostrar la nueva clase en la vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo tuve un problema similar, en el cual necesitaba enviar 2 modelos o listas al `View` para mostrar, lo resolvi de la siguiente forma:

Lo resolvi creando un clase con los siguiente datos de las listas a enviar al `View`:

```
public class UnionListasViewModel
{
    public List<persona> persona { get; set; }
    public List<cliente> cliente { get; set; }

}
```

y en el `ActionResult` asigne los datos a un objeto y se lo envie al `View`

```
public ActionResult Clientes()
{
    private PruebaContext cc = new chalupaContext();
    public UnionListasViewModel modelNuevo = new UnionListasViewModel ();
    modelNuevo.persona = cc.personas.ToList();
    modelNuevo.cliente= cc.clientes.ToList();
    return View(modelNuevo);
}
```

ya en el `View` no llamas a la listas individuales sino al `ViewModel` creado (`UnionListasViewModel`)

Comment: Para mejores practicas es recomendable crear Vista (en este caso que no representa una entidad sino un resultView) con el nombre igual que el action, ejemplo: ClientesView, si fuera para el Index... ClienteIndexView.  Así ya sabes que este objeto fue creado exactamente para ser usado en una vista especifica.  Es en base a mi experiencia en proyectos, pero cada quien decide sus nombres.  Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo utilizando **AutoMapper**, no se si se ajuste  a tu caso o si es lo que estas buscando:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Bogus;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnirListas
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientes = GenerarClientes(5);
            var personas = GenerarPersonas(5);
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Persona, PersonaGenerica>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.IdPersona))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Nombre, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.NombreDeLaPersona))
                    .ForMember(d => d.EsCliente, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => false));
                cfg.CreateMap<Cliente, PersonaGenerica>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.IdCliente))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Nombre, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.NombreDelCliente))
                    .ForMember(d => d.EsCliente, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => true));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var clientesGenericos = mapper.Map<List<PersonaGenerica>>(clientes);
            var personasGenericas = mapper.Map<List<PersonaGenerica>>(personas);

            List<PersonaGenerica> result = new List<PersonaGenerica>();
            result.AddRange(clientesGenericos);
            result.AddRange(personasGenericas);

            PrintResults(clientes, personas, result);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public class PersonaGenerica
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public bool EsCliente { get; set; }
        }

        public class Persona
        {
            public int IdPersona { get; set; }
            public string NombreDeLaPersona { get; set; }
        }

        public class Cliente
        {
            public int IdCliente { get; set; }
            public string NombreDelCliente { get; set; }
        }

        private static List<Persona> GenerarPersonas(int numeroAGenerar)
        {
            List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroAGenerar; i++)
            {
                personas.Add(new Persona() { IdPersona = new Faker().Random.Int(1, 9999), NombreDeLaPersona = new Faker().Person.FullName });
            }

            return personas;
        }

        private static List<Cliente> GenerarClientes(int numeroAGenerar)
        {
            List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroAGenerar; i++)
            {
                clientes.Add(new Cliente() { IdCliente = new Faker().Random.Int(1, 9999), NombreDelCliente = new Faker().Person.FullName });
            }

            return clientes;
        }

        private static void PrintResults(List<Cliente> clientes, List<Persona> personas, List<PersonaGenerica> results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLIENTES:");
            foreach (var c in clientes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Cliente: {c.IdCliente}-{c.NombreDelCliente}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("PERSONAS:");
            foreach (var p in personas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Persona: {p.IdPersona}-{p.NombreDeLaPersona}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("JUNTOS:");
            foreach (var r in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Persona: {r.Id}-{r.Nombre}-EsCliente:{(r.EsCliente ? "SI" : "No")}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que AutoMapper funcione tienes que definirle como se va ha realizar el mapeo, para eso se utiliza config que se muestra en el codigo, la verdad es muy simple le dices para este campo usa este otro.

Una vez configurado el `mapper` solo llamas a `mapper.map`, esta función convertirá tu objecto en el tipo de objeto especificado.

Una vez que tengo las dos listas convertidas a una lista Generica común.. solo uso el método `AddRange()` para agregar la lista actual a la nueva lista con el resutaldo.

***NOTA** : Puedes hacer lo mismo que hace el mapper a pie, osea utilizando ciclos `for` o con `linq`

Algo así seria convertir `Cliente` a `PersonaGenercia` utilizando linq:

```
var clientesGenericos = clientes
            .Select(x => new PersonaGenerica()
            {
                Id = x.IdCliente,
                Nombre = x.NombreDelCliente
            }).ToList();
```

¿Cuál es la ventaja de utilizar `automapper`?, pues puedes tener el `mapper` para toda tu aplicación y utilizarlo cada vez que lo necesites en cualquier parte sin tener que estar repitiendo instrucciones de `linq`.